# Prove that every linear map has the form $f(x)=ax$

Tags: linear-algebra

By definition, a function $ f: \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is linear iff

1. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$
2. $ f(bx) = bf(x)$ $ \forall b,x \in \mathbb{R}$

I am trying to prove the following statement:

If $ f $ is a linear map defined above then $f$ has the following form: $f(x)=ax$ $ \forall x \in\mathbb{R}$.

Could you give a suggestion about where to start from?

Comment: the last statement is not true, there is a such as for every x , f(x) = ax, not the other way around.

Comment: yeah, it should not be "for all $a$"

Comment: I edited your post to bring it into conformity with these comments.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, mine was wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is difficult to give a first step without giving away the whole solution, since the solution consists of just one step:
$$f(x)=x \cdot f(1)=f(1) \cdot x$$

Comment: So, we define $f(1)=a $. Thank you. I feel ashamed but now I know :)

Answer (score 1):

- if part: $a(x+y) = (ax) + (ay)$ and $a(bx) = b(ax)$.
- only if part: $f(x)=f(x\cdot1)=xf(1)=ax$.